# Buffer returned by child_process.execSync is incomplete

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have the following script which executes a shell command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const { execSync } = require('child_process');

try {
    const data = execSync(
        'yarn licenses generate-disclaimer --prod',
        { encoding: 'utf8', maxBuffer: 50 * 1024 * 1024 }
    );

    console.log(data.length);

    return true;
} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to generate disclaimer: ${error.message}`);
    return false;
}
```

`data` is a `Buffer` containing `stdout` of the child process. As I understand, the way to convert it to a string is to use the `.toString()` method, but in my case the string is incomplete. The command I am trying to execute is supposed to produce ~500 KB of data, but `buffer.length` is 43741 (that's ~43 KB).

The problem is probably that `yarn licenses` output contains some special characters which result in the buffer being incomplete. If I replace the command with `printf "%0.s-" {1..500000}`, the buffer is complete.

I am using the latest node version (8.7.0).

Any thoughts/suggestions?

---

*EDIT:* Appending `| tr "\0" "\n"` to the command increases the buffer size to ~122 KB, so @YaroslavAdmin is definitely looking in the right direction. The result is still incomplete though. How do I make sure all special characters are escaped?

Comment: I suspect that command prints some special character, which causes Node to strip remaining output. `\0` maybe.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `.toString()` after execSync.

```
const data = execSync(
    'yarn licenses generate-disclaimer --prod',
    { encoding: 'utf8', maxBuffer: 50 * 1024 * 1024 }
).toString(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: Why use toString() when encoding is already specified ? @junvar

Comment: Because execSync returns a buffer, not a string.

Comment: In Node 16.2.0, if I provide `encoding`, `execSync` returns a string, so `.toString` is not needed.